# How to write a Django test that checks whether an error occurs on a page?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I'm currently debugging a pull request that has made a certain page error out:

[image]

The view is subclassed from Django's generic `UpdateView`, and corresponds to the `check-ins` tab of a URL named `'family'` in the `dashboard` app:

```
url(
    r'^families/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/'
    r'(?P<tab>case-management|scheduling|family-demographics|activation-payment|check-ins)$',
    views.FamilyUpdate.as_view(),
    name='family'),
```

As a first step, I'd like to write a test which captures what I see, namely, an error occurring, so that after I fix it I can be sure it never happens again.

How can achieve this? I've tried the following test case,

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse
from lucy_web.test_factories import FamilyFactory, UserFactory


class TestDashboardNavigation(TestCase):
    '''Test class to simply navigate to pages and click the links, making sure no errors occur'''
    def setUp(self):
        self.client.force_login(UserFactory(is_superuser=True))

    def test_family_navigation(self):
        family = FamilyFactory()
        for tab in ["case-management", "scheduling", "family-demographics", "activation-payment", "check-ins"]:
            url = reverse('dashboard:family', kwargs={'pk': family.id, 'tab': tab})
            response = self.client.get(url)
            print(response.status_code)
```

where `FamilyFactory` is a `factory_boy` test fixture which creates a `Family` object (the underlying model of the `UpdateView`), but this test simply passes:

```
(venv) Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy-web kurtpeek$ python manage.py test dashboard.tests.test_navigation
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
302
302
302
302
302
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 1.294s

OK
```

How would I catch errors like this occurring on a page?

Comment: Your code is referring to an attribute. you would need to test for the attribute. 

Can you post your model, the form corresponding to the model and the stack trace that was cut off from the first screen shot?

The part im interested in the screen shot is the line thats bolded and shows what part of the web app errored out

Comment: also another thing worth noting is that a webpage does not throw server level errors in debug mode. you would get a 302 redirect because you are seeing a stacktrace. i bet if you turned off debug you would see a 502 error.

Comment: Regarding your last comment about debug mode, I tried decorating the test function with `@override_settings(DEBUG=False)`, but I still get the same result (all `302` status codes and the test passes).